# Aligning text on both sides of a image in a navbar (html and css)

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, navbar

I want to have an image in the middle navbar that I have made but the text on the right gets pushed far away! how do I fix this?

This is what my Navbar looks like in the HTML:

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: Forgot to include it! let me fix that!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RPY1niRc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for can be achieved quite easily with flexbox.

I don't have access to your CSS so I added a little bit myself just to demonstrate the basic principle in this codepen: https://codepen.io/Ardiaz/pen/zJRKmR

Key notes here are as below:

```
display: flex;
```

This will declare your element as a flex element, which enables the suite of css declarations available in flex.

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

This will space all your elements evenly across the page, with the image in the centre as it is the centre most item within your  element.

Comment: I didn't allow me to paste my css for some reason so I did a pastebin https://pastebin.com/RPY1niRc Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark this as the correct answer if you feel it satisfied your question!

Comment: I've edited the codepen to demonstrate the code working as intended. https://codepen.io/Ardiaz/pen/zJRKmR - with flex, you don't need to assign floats. Floats are generally considered legacy technology these days with flex support for all modern browsers being so good, so i'd recommend taking a look at flex fundamentals to get a better understanding of what's going on here.

Comment: Also, just noticed that my codepen uses SCSS (my general go to) so i've changed this to CSS, this should now work correctly for you if you implement everything exactly as shown in the codepen.

Answer (score 0):

This can be quite easily done with flexbox, just replace the "#logo" with your image in the following code below.

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">Artwork</a>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <a href="">Responses</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
}

#logo{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

**Result:**
https://jsfiddle.net/3L7b94fr/

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try now!

Comment: I didn't get this to work. (I'm new to this) could you take a look at my CSS (before I did any changes) and tell me where I should do the changes you proposed? https://pastebin.com/RPY1niRc